# What does the <% $Resources:My.Resource %> access?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I tried searching, but I guess the <% $ %> triggers something on google and it turns up nothing. What is this accessing in an asp.net .aspx page? I've used the = but never a $.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has to do with expressions.
Here's another example :

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" Runat="server" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Employees]"
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:NorthwindConnectionString1 %>" />
```

Here ya go : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5bd1tad.aspx

I've not used Resources before but, here is some more information from MSDN : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa905797.aspx

Answer (score 1):

It uses the global resource file under the App_GlobalResources directory. This syntax is used when you want to assign the string directly to property of a asp.net server control.
For ex:

```
<asp:Label id="label1" runat="server" text="<%$ Resources: ResourceFileName, Label1String %>" />
```

Also see the link provided in rib.usa's answer which has more information.